# can a forms action url contain querystring values?

Tags: asp.net, html, forms, query-string, asp.net-mvc

can a forms action url contain querystring values?

Comment: Change the method to `GET` instead of `POST`

Comment: Sample code about it for more explain question and more details for answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

it can.

## But

when `method="get"` then the querystring will be stripped out and replaced by the form input names/values (since the form controls are those that build the `GET` querystring).

```
<form method="get" action="?param=foo">
    <input type="hidden" name="param" value="bar" />
</form>
```

will submit `param=bar`

To keep the value you should specify `method="post"` on the `form`.

```
<form method="post" action="?param=foo">
    <input type="hidden" name="otherparam" value="bar" />
</form>
```

will submit `param=foo&otherparam=bar`

```
<form method="post" action="?param=foo">
    <input type="hidden" name="param" value="bar" />
</form>
```

will submit `param=foo&param=bar` (so, depending on how you process the request, you could get either an array value or unexpected results).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can.

(Keystrokes)

Comment: @Kiquenet: It's a "can you do X" question, it hardly needs any sample code. I'll rather vote to close this as a dupe of a better question that has more discussion about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked using a reduced test case:

- Form.htm that contains a form with an `action` of `default.aspx?query=1` and a submit button.
- default.aspx that contains code in `Page_Load` to write out `Request.QueryString["query"]`

The result I got when clicking on the button was a page that read:

> 1

So, the answer is yes.